# Discord4j getting a username from id

Tags: java, discord4j

is there any way in Discord4j to get someone's username using their id? The only way I have found so far is using `UserData.builder().id("id").username("username").discriminator("0000").build();`, but this requires you to manualy specify a username. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be building D4J `DataX` classes yourself. `DataX` classes are the raw JSON mappings of what Discord sends and are mapped using Jackson.

To get a user from ID:
`GatewayDiscordClient#getUserFromId(userId)`